# Sending scheduled emails in a spring application?

Tags: spring, html-email, activiti, autosys

I need to achieve the following : -

1. Sending emails to around 6000 users around 30 times in a year. Sometimes sending emails at specific time of  day else at midnight.
2. I need to provide retry functionality in my application, so if by some reason my application failed to send email to some of the user it should retry to send 3 times (till 3 days) before finally marking it as failure.
3. i need to send emails using predefined templates but having dynamic data in it.

My application tech stack - java, spring boot 1.4, oracle database, CA autosys job scheduler, activiti bpm (not using Activiti as of now but can use it if it is the best solution)

My current solution :-

1. Use autosys scheduler to define these jobs.
2. calling my Rest exposed services (spring + java + oracle tech stack), that perform all the application logic and them Apache commons email to send the email using my smtp server.

My question - What is the recommended way to send email in this case? As i have to maintain various tables to achieve retry functionality. should i use activiti instead of autosys scheduler? Or spring framework itself for this email scheduling?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any **business processes** to be managed in your problem. as far as no business people are involved in any task (such as filling a form, make a decision based on input provided), you should avoid activiti. **Activiti is a BPM engine**, there is no use of it unless you are managing a process. for schedulers you should definitely go ahead with the spring framework. *Do let me know if i've missed any point.*